# How do I setup a Gmail vacation responder for an imported account?

Tags: gmail

I have multiple accounts imported into Gmail with labels set up and skipping the inbox.

I was wondering if it's possible to use the Automatic Vacation Responder for one of those imported accounts (e.g., work email, not personal email) rather than the main personal Gmail account (from which I imported the other email accounts).

Is it? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most email systems have the vacation response feature, just log into the original email account and set it up. Just remember to turn it off when you return.